# docker0 bridge status toggles between enabled/disabled, what could be causing that?

Tags: linux-networking, bridge, docker, coreos

I have some CoreOS bare metal instances that are displaying unusual behaviour on the docker0 bridge device.

On one of the instances where this has been occurring, I'm running couchbase server and it has caused some issues with rebalancing.  When I moved couchbase to a node where this wasn't happening that problem went away.

What could be causing it?  what determines the state of the bridge device?

hardware is identical.  Configuration is identical except IP address.

See the following output:

```
[   11.219278] igb 0000:02:00.1 eno2: renamed from eth1
[   11.233382] igb 0000:02:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[   11.254416] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: commit=600
[   11.458737] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ib0: link is not ready
[   11.579397] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno2: link is not ready
[   11.698029] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[   12.010779] bridge: automatic filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables has been deprecated. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   12.024156] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
[   12.036945] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   12.051018] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[   14.650802] igb 0000:02:00.0 eno1: igb: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[   14.660237] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
[   14.742461] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): ib0: link becomes ready
[   45.805457] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[  111.008838] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vetha6b1e7a: link is not ready
[  111.015941] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vetha6b1e7a: link becomes ready
[  111.023065] device veth7ef24ab entered promiscuous mode
[  111.043171] eth0: renamed from vetha6b1e7a
[  112.009927] docker0: port 1(veth7ef24ab) entered forwarding state
[  112.016158] docker0: port 1(veth7ef24ab) entered forwarding state
[  112.022483] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): docker0: link becomes ready
[  112.099447] docker0: port 1(veth7ef24ab) entered disabled state
[  112.107076] device veth7ef24ab left promiscuous mode
[  112.112173] docker0: port 1(veth7ef24ab) entered disabled state
[  122.461130] device vethf877e85 entered promiscuous mode
[  122.466924] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethf877e85: link is not ready
[  122.473684] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethf877e85: link becomes ready
[  122.480738] docker0: port 1(vethf877e85) entered forwarding state
[  122.486970] docker0: port 1(vethf877e85) entered forwarding state
[  122.506427] eth0: renamed from vethf26c9f2
[  122.632319] docker0: port 1(vethf877e85) entered disabled state
[  122.639992] device vethf877e85 left promiscuous mode
[  122.645123] docker0: port 1(vethf877e85) entered disabled state
[  132.921279] device vethb82e1be entered promiscuous mode
[  132.927131] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethb82e1be: link is not ready
[  132.933864] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethb82e1be: link becomes ready
[  132.940925] docker0: port 1(vethb82e1be) entered forwarding state
[  132.947184] docker0: port 1(vethb82e1be) entered forwarding state
[  132.964347] eth0: renamed from veth6449c8e
[  133.013215] docker0: port 1(vethb82e1be) entered disabled state
[  133.021003] device vethb82e1be left promiscuous mode
[  133.026104] docker0: port 1(vethb82e1be) entered disabled state
[  143.403885] device vethddb7ee6 entered promiscuous mode
[  143.409539] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethdd4d268: link is not ready
[  143.416339] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethdd4d268: link becomes ready
[  143.433351] eth0: renamed from vethdd4d268
[  144.404045] docker0: port 1(vethddb7ee6) entered forwarding state
[  144.410292] docker0: port 1(vethddb7ee6) entered forwarding state
[  144.480602] docker0: port 1(vethddb7ee6) entered disabled state
[  144.488347] device vethddb7ee6 left promiscuous mode
[  144.493480] docker0: port 1(vethddb7ee6) entered disabled state
[  154.925053] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethadcefb2: link is not ready
[  154.931794] device veth6087f8b entered promiscuous mode
[  154.937610] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethadcefb2: link becomes ready
[  154.956632] eth0: renamed from vethadcefb2
[  155.924469] docker0: port 1(veth6087f8b) entered forwarding state
[  155.930718] docker0: port 1(veth6087f8b) entered forwarding state
[  156.007957] docker0: port 1(veth6087f8b) entered disabled state
[  156.015658] device veth6087f8b left promiscuous mode
[  156.020781] docker0: port 1(veth6087f8b) entered disabled state
[  166.387105] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth407dccf: link is not ready
[  166.394294] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth407dccf: link becomes ready
[  166.401417] device veth8f92cbb entered promiscuous mode
[  166.420099] eth0: renamed from veth407dccf
[  167.386861] docker0: port 1(veth8f92cbb) entered forwarding state
[  167.393107] docker0: port 1(veth8f92cbb) entered forwarding state
[  167.476477] docker0: port 1(veth8f92cbb) entered disabled state
[  167.484157] device veth8f92cbb left promiscuous mode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common behavior for Docker bridges. The bridge state changes every time a container comes up or goes down.

Does it impact couchbase?

Comment: I thought it was, but it seems not.  But it's interesting behaviour nontheless.

Comment: So that original problem was issues with Couchbase server crashing and the container stopping and restarting which caused the bridge device to change state regularly.  So you were right, the bridge state changes based on the container going down and coming back up.